# Reloading circle Component

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I am trying to animate a circle svg with Blazor.  I have seen this done with the Tetris game so it should be possible i just cant figure out how to get it working.

```
<svg width="600" height="400">
    <Ball Height="@Ball.Height" Width="@Ball.Width" CurrentPosition="@Ball.CurrentPosition"></Ball>
</svg>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@Bounce">bounce</button>
```

## Component

```
@inherits BallModel;
@using Blong.Client.Model

<circle cx="@CurrentPosition.X" cy="@CurrentPosition.Y" r="@Radius" style="@Style" />
```

## bounce code

```
 void Bounce()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(() => SetPosition(Ball.CurrentPosition.X, Ball.CurrentPosition.Y++, GameHeight));
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> SetPosition(int x, int y, int LastRow)
    {

        if (y <= LastRow)
        {
            Ball.CurrentPosition.Y++;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

This does kind of work.  Every time i push the button my ball hops to the new position.  Is there some way to get this to reload as it goes though the loop?  I am trying to see my ball moving around the screen.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675814/842935

Comment: Hi @DalmTo, how you get "Ball" tag, can you share some code, I have to draw circle with progress in percentages

Comment: The project is on Github https://github.com/LindaLawton/BlazorGames  Enjoy i haven't touched it since, I have no idea if it will work with the current version of Blazor.  So no promises 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it should be enough to notify the `Blazor` to update the UI within the loop:

```
StateHasChanged();
```

But there are few things. First the `SetPosition` method doesn’t contain any awaits and would be run synchronously.

Then the `Bounce` could be made async, instead of creating new Tasks on your own, in case you don’t want to block the main Thread.

Also the `GameHeight` seems like a constant or static within a current View’s state and as such I would directly reference it within the called method, instead of passing it as a parameter, but that is just a personal opinion.

Another thing would be, to make sure the Bounce is not called multiple times while already „bouncing“.

And I think the logic coils be simplified a bit.

Here is my suggestion:

```cs
public async Task Bounce()
{
  if(Bouncing) return;

  Bouncing = true;

  while(Ball.CurrentPosition.Y <= GameHeight)
  {
    Ball.CurrentPosition.Y++;
    StateHasChanged();
    await Task.Delay(500);
  }
// in case View has been resized, make sure Ball is not out of boundaries
  Ball.CurrentPosition.Y = GameHeight;
  StateHasChanged();
  Bouncing = false;
}
```

Comment: I actually just got it working using the exact same thing :)  I am off to work out some edge collision detection

Comment: Glad to hear we share the same ideas. I also think it’s better to get it to work first, write it down and refactor it afterwards

Comment: I have been digging around in the Testris code but its so far out of date that most of it doesn't really work.