# Blazor JsInterop Invoke after each promise resolves

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Trying to get things working correctly in Blazor Server Side App. I have an Uploader Component but it doesn't InvokeAsync after each promise is resolved on client side. It waits for all Images to load then Invokes the C# method. How would I get it to Invoke the C# method after each image is loaded?

I know JavaScript is single threaded but also tried with web workers and still does the same thing.

Sample repo can be found here
https://dev.azure.com/twinnaz/BlazorUploader

Gif of what's happening.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rj7Q.jpg

It should be able to invoke the C# method Async in parallel from javascript file if my thinking is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related with Blazor and JS. On JS you are not awaiting for `GenerateImageData`.

You should to use a modern `for … of`loop instead, in which `await` will work as expected:

```
GetFileInputFiles = async (instance, fileInput) => {
    var files = Array.from(fileInput.files);
    for (const image of files) {
        var imagedata = await readUploadedFileAsText(image);
        console.log("sending");
        _ = await instance.invokeMethodAsync('GenerateImageData', imagedata);
        console.log("sent");
    };
};
```

On Blazor, I suggest to you to rewrite `GenerateImageData` as :

```
    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task GenerateImageData(string data)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine( "Receiving"  );
        ImageBase64.Add(data);
        await Task.Delay(1);
        StateHasChanged();
        System.Console.WriteLine( "Received"  );
    }
```

Result:

[image]

- More detailed info about JS issue: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/842935)
- More detailed info about Blazor issue: [Blazor - Display wait or spinner on API call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675814/842935)

Comment: Thanks helped a lot !!! Ended up doing it a slightly different way but your knowledge lead to doing more searching and found a better solution to preview the images. I'll update repo with the new code tonight.

Answer (score 0):

```js
GeneratePreviewImages = async (dotNet, fileInput) => {

    const files = Array.from(fileInput.files);

    const imageSrcs = files.map(file => getPreviewImageSrc(file));
    loop(imageSrcs, dotNet);
};



const loop = async (arr, dotNet) => {
    for await (const src of arr) {
        console.log(src);
        dotNet.invokeMethodAsync('GenerateImageData', src);
    }
};

const getPreviewImageSrc = async (file) => {
  return  URL.createObjectURL(file);
};
```