# Disabling button from async function in Blazor

Tags: validation, asynchronous, blazor, blazor-client-side, matblazor

I have following EditForm model on my page:

```
<EditForm Model="@projectParameters" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitProject">
       <MatButton Raised="true" Type="submit" Disabled="@saveButtonDisabled">@saveButtonName</MatButton>
</EditForm>
```

Then the following functions:

```
private async Task SubmitProject()
    {
        DisableSave();

        if (pageType == "Create")
        {
            await CreateProject();
        }
        else if (pageType == "Create")
        {
           await EditProject();
        }
    }
```

and

```
void DisableSave()
    {
        saveButtonDisabled = true;
        saveButtonName = "Saving...";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

SubmitProject & DisableSave are properly called, but the saveButtonName & disabled never actually show as completed when CreateProject is working.  What am I missing?

Comment: This is a very crude way to do the trick...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flush changes with `await Task.Delay(1);`:

```
private async Task SubmitProject()
{
    await DisableSave();
    ...
```

Then

```
async Task DisableSave()
{
    saveButtonDisabled = true;
    saveButtonName = "Saving...";
    await Task.Delay(1); //flush changes
    StateHasChanged(); // not needed
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks!!  Could you explain why though? I still have trouble understanding some async stuff sometimes.

Comment: It's not about async, is about virtual DOM, diffs only are send at end of call, releasing UI thread diffs are also send. This is the way I found to do it, but I don't if this is the better way, is how I do it.

Comment: I have another clever answer about this subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675814/842935 Just checkout.