# StateHasChanged not detecting changes first time

Tags: c#, rendering, blazor

It seems that `StateHasChanged()` only triggers the re-render of the component after an await operation on a Task (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932854/statehaschanged-re-render-the-component-one-time-out-of-two)).

So I want to use only `StateHasChanged` for re-rendering rather than using `Task.delay` or `Task.Run`.

Here is my code:

```
protected async Task ClearSearch()
        {
            SearchTestCoupon = new Mechanic.Shared.TestCouponSearch();
            IsBusy = true;
            TestCouponGroups = new List<Mechanic.Shared.TestCouponGroup>();
            StateHasChanged();  // << -------- **FIRST TIME** 
            //await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await GetTestCouponGroups(SearchTestCoupon);
        }

 protected async Task GetTestCouponGroups(object args)
        {
                TestCouponGroups = await TestCouponService.GetTestCouponGroupsAsync(SearchTestCoupon);
                IsRowSelected = false;
                IsBusy = false;
                StateHasChanged(); // << -------- **SECOND TIME**
        }
```

Here I use loader which is activate using `IsBusy`. But It is not working the first time when `StateHasChanged` is called as mentioned in the code.

But it renders component as expected the second time.

I have used `Task.Delay` but it is breaking my other functionalities like clearing grid and showing searched data etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932854/statehaschanged-re-render-the-component-one-time-out-of-two

Comment: I put that in question also

Comment: Your question is the same, but you don't like the answer?

Comment: I don't want to use Task.Delay or Task.Run as I mentioned above in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StateHasChanged` doesn't re-render the component, the component re-render when events delegates (`OnClick, OnMouseMouve...`) finished.

So in your case, if you want to re-render the component on the first `StateHasChanged` your code should be :

```cs
protected void ClearSearch()
        {
            SearchTestCoupon = new Mechanic.Shared.TestCouponSearch();
            IsBusy = true;
            TestCouponGroups = new List<Mechanic.Shared.TestCouponGroup>();            
            GetTestCouponGroups(SearchTestCoupon); // don't await 
            StateHasChanged();  // << -------- **FIRST TIME** 
        }

 protected async Task GetTestCouponGroups(object args)
        {
                TestCouponGroups = await TestCouponService.GetTestCouponGroupsAsync(SearchTestCoupon);
                IsRowSelected = false;
                IsBusy = false;
                StateHasChanged(); // << -------- **SECOND TIME**
        }
```

Comment: It worked for me ! but still I am using async method and I should call await for that method.So I don't understand what happened there but it worked. can you explain it in answer ?

Comment: Because the component is render when it exits the method. if you await it will be re rendered after `GetTestCouponGroups`finished.