# Blazor Server Side - Value changed in Child function is not updating UI

Tags: blazor, .net-core-3.1

So what I am doing here is, I have a progress bar in my child component(RMSBaseComponent.razor) which is surrounded by a condition variable "IsLoading"

```
<div style="padding:20px">

@* Page Title *@
<h3>@PageTitle</h3>
<MatDivider></MatDivider>

@* Loader *@
@if (IsLoading)
{
    <MatProgressBar Indeterminate="true"></MatProgressBar>
}
</div>
```

I am making this Child in Parent(AddNewCity.razor) as

```
<RMSBaseComponent PageTitle="Add New City" @ref="BaseComponent">

</RMSBaseComponent>
```

Here I am getting the reference of child in "BaseComponent" variable but when I change the value of "IsLoading" from parent component class (AddNewCity.cs) it does not update the UI and not showing "MatProgressBar" UI. I am changing value as below

```
public partial class AddNewCity
{
    private RMSBaseComponent BaseComponent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        BaseComponent.IsLoading = true;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604886/blazor-display-wait-or-spinner-on-api-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `StateHasChanged()` after `Thread.Sleep()`

```
public partial class AddNewCity
    {
        private RMSBaseComponent BaseComponent { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
        {
            base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            BaseComponent.IsLoading = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would also advise that you consider passing such references as a `Parameter` to the child component - if the child needs to mutate the state of their parent even some two-way binding or at least an event might be in order. Personally, I prefer raising events from the child components so their parents can decide what to do with that (like, toggle a loading sign, or fetch other data).

Comment: StateHasChanged(); saved my life. Thank you.