# Loading indicator in blazor page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am writing an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application with bazor pages.

I want to fire a (slow) server-side calculation with the user clicks on a button.

What i want is to put a "loading..." message during calculation and then, display the message.

Here is what i've done in my C# Service class:

```
    public async Task<String> traitement1(String argument)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5);  // I want to simulate a very slow calculation
        return await Task.FromResult("Finished ! Here is your result...");
    }
```

And here is what i've done in my bazor page:

```
<p>@my_result</p>

<button @onclick="@on_btn_click">Click me</button>

@code 
{
    private String my_result = "";

    private async void on_btn_click()
    {
        my_result = "Loading...";
        my_result = await mon_service.traitement1("aaa");
    }
}
```

It does not work... Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor - Display wait or spinner on API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604886/blazor-display-wait-or-spinner-on-api-call)

Comment: I hope you realise that `Thread.Sleep(5)` will delay the code for 5 milliseconds? Not enough time for the browser to register a change of state and re-render. Also, you should almost **never** use `async void`. And don't use `Thread.Sleep` - for Task-based async methods use `Task.Delay(5000)` for a 5-second delay

Answer (score 2):

First of all, avoid  `async void`.  Blazor fully supports `async Task` event handlers:

```
private async Task on_btn_click()
{
    my_result = "Loading...";
    await Task.Delay(1);   // give the Renderer a chance to catch up
    my_result = await mon_service.traitement1("aaa");
}
```

You need to insert the `Task.Delay(1);` because your `traitement1()` is not really async, it never gives up the Thread it runs on. `Task.Yield()` would have been clearer but it does not always work.

There is no need to call StateHasChanged() here.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last point? Why not call StateHasChanged()?

Comment: @ChrisJensen - Because Blazor already puts a StateHasChanged()  before and after the event. The before one is consumed in Delay(1) and show "Loading.." , the after one shows the results.

Comment: In other words, you can only omit the StateHasChanged call the first time if you have multiple updates triggered by the same event, correct?

Comment: No, you can always omit it unless you need > 2 screen updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have a component that can use. I just updated it to where you can either do the percentage complete yourself for a process, or you can set it to just increment on a periodic basis if you know about how long your process takes.

Nuget if you don't want to copy the code: DataJuggler.Blazor.Components

If you don't use the Nuget, you will need circle.scss:

(download from my GitHub)
https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components/blob/master/wwwroot/css/circle.scss

Author who deserves credit is:

Andre Firchow

http://circle.firchow.net/

Either way, you will need to add it to your _host.cshtml file:

Nuget package way is shown here:

```
<link href="~/_content/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components/css/circle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or if the circle.scss is in your project file

```
<link href="~/css/circle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I tried to post ProgressBar.razor and Progress.razor.cs code, but stack overflow told me I went over your 30,000 character limit, which I find hard to believe as little code as it is, so here is the link:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components/blob/master/ProgressBar.razor

https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components/blob/master/ProgressBar.razor.cs

Usage:

```
<div class="progresscontainer3">
    <ProgressBar Subscriber=this Increment="0" Interval="125" 
    ClientHandledIncrement="true" 
    CloseAtExtraPercent="0" Visible="@ShowProgress" Theme=ThemeEnum.Dark 
    Color=ColorEnum.Orange
    Size=SizeEnum.Small OverrideThemeColorForText="true" TextColor="White">
    </ProgressBar>
</div>
```

If you want to see a working example, Sign Up or upload an image, type in this query:

https://pixeldatabase.net

Hide
Total < 40

and click Apply.

Or there is a video here that also shows the progress bar:

https://youtu.be/K-reLOc1-Uo

I think it works pretty well.